# Proof that the acceleration points to the center

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, vectors

> The equation of movement of a certain particle on the plane XY is given by: $\vec r=4\cos(3t)\hat{i}+4\sin(3t)\hat{j}$ m where t is in seconds.
> Prove that the vector acceleration always points to the center and that the magnitude of such acceleration satisifies $|\vec{a}|=\frac{|\vec{v}|^2}{r}$

I have gotten $\vec{a}=-36\cos(3t)\hat{i}-36\sin(3t)\hat{j}
$ by differentiating twice

But I have no clue on how to approach this or what to do to start with

Comment: $\vec r$ is a vector from the origin(center) to the position of the particle. Since $\vec a = -9 \vec r$ it is in the opposite direction as $\vec r$. So it's from the particle towards the center. Get $\vec v$ by differentiating $\vec r$ once which you've already done. Then you can check the magnitude formula.

Comment: oh! i get it now! thanks but why should i differentiate r to get v? im not asked to get v

Comment: the magnitude formula for $|\vec a|$ has $|\vec v|$ in it. And also $r = |\vec r|$. You're asked to prove the magnitude formula in the question.

Comment: oh oops, okay let me try that and if i don't answer this it means i understood it. Thanks so far